# Trouble retrieving DataFrame using SQLAlchemy and psycopg2 - works with create_engine but not with psycopg2

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm facing an issue when trying to execute the following code snippet using `psycopg2` in place of `create_engine`.

```py
# Code snippet using create_engine (works fine):
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

db_url = "your_database_url_here"
engine = create_engine(db_url)

# Establish a connection
connection = engine.connect()

sql_query = "your_table_name"
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, con=connection)
```

This successfully returns a `DataFrame` if the `your_table_name` table is present in the database.

When I replicate the exact same code using `psycopg2`, it throws an error. Here's the modified code:

```py
# Code snippet using psycopg2 (throws error):
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

db_url = "your_database_url_here"
conn = psycopg2.connect(db_url)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_query = "your_table_name"

# The following line throws an error
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, con=conn)
```

I've verified that the table exists in the database. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

In the provided code snippets, I used `SQLAlchemy` with `create_engine` to establish a connection and retrieve a `DataFrame` using `pd.read_sql`. This worked successfully when querying a table named `your_table_name`.

However, when attempting to replicate the same functionality using `psycopg2`, an error occurred during the execution of `pd.read_sql`:

```
Execution failed on sql 'transaction': syntax error at or near "your_table_name"
LINE 1: your_table_name
        ^
```

Comment: 1) What is you are trying to accomplish with `psycopg2` that can't be accomplished using `SQLAlchemy`? 2) You have not indicated what URI you are using, but I'm betting it is using `psycopg2` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html):

> **sql**: *str or SQLAlchemy Selectable (select or text object)*
> SQL query to be executed or a table name.
>
> **con**: *SQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection*
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported. The user is responsible for engine disposal and connection closure for the SQLAlchemy connectable; str connections are closed automatically. See here.

So if you don't use `SQLAlchemy`, you should only use `sqlite` connection even if `psycopg2` is compliant to DBAPI 2.0 specification else you will receive a `UserWarning`:

```
UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
```

However, this is not the reason why your code raised an error. Actually you can only pass a table name when using `SQLAlchemy` otherwise you have to pass a SQL query.

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name"
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, con=conn)
...
UserWarning: ...
```

My advice: either you use SQLAlchemy with Pandas, or you use [connectorx](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x) to load your data (read-only!):

```
#! pip install connectorx
import connectorx as cx

db_url = "your_database_url_here"
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name"
df = cx.read_sql(db_url, sql_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go this route then:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db_name user=user_name", cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from some_table")

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cur.fetchall())

con.close()
```